# How to convert Mat data(OpenCV, data format for image) into unity3d texutre

Tags: c++, opencv, unity-game-engine, textures, mat

I know Mat data save each pixel data(RGB data in a column) as a unsigned char. And texture data in unity3d is byte[]. I try to do the following thing, but the result is not right, the image capture from the camera displayed in the hwind is not right.

```
Mat src_frame;//this is every frame that captured from the current camera
D3DLOCKED_RECT d3d_rect;
byte *pSrc = src_frame.data;
byte *pDest = (byte *)d3d_rect.pBits;

int stride = d3d_rect.Pitch;
int pixel_w_size = src_frame.cols;
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < src_frame.rows; i++){
    memcpy(pDest, pSrc, pixel_w_size);
    pDest += stride;
    pSrc += pixel_w_size;
}
```

Only gray image shows, I don't know why this happens. Does the Mat data sequence is different from the texture data? Their data both contain the RGB information.

Answer (score 0):

`pixel_w_size` should be `src_frame.cols` multiplied with the bytes per pixel (3 in case of RGB) or even better use `elemSize()`.

So use:

`int pixel_w_size = src_frame.cols * src_frame.elemSize();`

Comment: That makes sense, however, `d3d_rect.Pitch` is only 1280. While the picture's size is `1024 * 1280`. So, `memcpy(pDest, pSrc, pixel_w_size)` will trigger an error.

Comment: I expect the `d3d_rect.Pitch` to be at least 3*1280. If this is not the case, it is probably allocated wrongly or for a greyscale picture? Pitch is the number of bytes per row, which can be larger than the number of pixels in a row.